# pip install Django on python3.6

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip, python-3.6

If I run `pip install Django` I get

> Requirement already satisfied: Django in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

I'd like to use python3.6 instead (which is already installed in `/usr/bin/python3.6`). What's the correct `pip` syntax to install the last version of Django on python 3.6?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to install pip3 :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Then, you have to work with `venv`

```
pip3 -p python3.6 virtualenv name
```

And you have to write :

```
pip3 install Django

#or specific version
pip3 install Django==1.10.5
```

Comment: I accept this answer because it was the first arrived and it precisely answer to my question. I read that using `venv` is a best practice thought :)

Comment: Thank you, I will edit with `venv`. But as you don't mention it in your question, I didn't use it ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you have **pip3** then directly use

`pip3 install Django`

Else try to use **virtualenv** for your python version as :

`pip -p python3.6 virtualenv name`

then you can install any version of Django on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can install it globally as others suggested, but the recommended way to install it is to use virtualenv or venv. In case you are using virtualenv (with virtualenvwrapper), just do

```
mkvirtualenv --python="path to python3 executable" "environment name"
pip install django
```

Inside virtual environment `pip` would be `pip3` by default and so is `python`.

Answer (score 1):

As is common with these sort of `pip` issues, before you install, check where `pip` is pointing to with `pip -V`.

If that points to Python `2`, you can then try `pip3 -V`; if that points to an older version of Python 3, go for `pip3.6`.

As a final approach, you can always go through `python` itself with `python3.6 -m pip install ..`.

Answer (score 1):

It means you already installed django in python2.7.

You can install django for python3 via:

```
pip3 install Django
```

---

You can also activate virtualenv, and run `pip install Django`