# How to change default version of pip3 from python3.5 to python3.6

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-16.04

I'm very new to python but I've learned the basics and now how it mostly works. I've been trying to install a Django framework for a server so that it can host a webpage.

Basically the problem here is that when I run commands such as:

```
python3 -V
```

I get the output

```
Python 3.6.1
```

But for some reason when using pip3 it decides to use the pip that is version specific to Python 3.5, for example doing:

```
pip3 install Django==1.11
```

installs Django in "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages" instead of the Python 3.6 counterpart of the dist-packages directory.

according to python documentations (https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html?highlight=pip#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel) I should be able to run this command:

```
python3.6 -m pip install SomePackage
```

to use the pip that is specific to Python 3.6, but this doesn't seem to work. I get an error saying "no module named pip" or "no module named pip3".

I am running on a server that uses Ubuntu 16.04

I appreciate all help, thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: I have tried running

```
pip3 -V
```

which gave me the output

```
pip 9.0.1 from /home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
```

From this I can say that I have no problems at all using python3 with Python 3.6, but when running pip3 it uses pip 9.0.1 from Python 3.5. Also running

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

gives me the output

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 98 not upgraded.
```

Comment: can you type which python command?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588925/pip-install-django-on-python3-6

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan There is no problems with using any python3 commands, python3 -V proves that. But it's the pip3 specific for 3.6 that I have problems with.

Comment: python3.6 can assert itself as the one to be used by pip with this command: `python3.6 -m ensurepip --default-pip`  then you can do a `pip3 install SomePackage` then the files go to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I once had the similar problem. And, I sort it out with following:

1. First install pip3 in your system

   ```
    sudo apt-get install python3-pip
   ```
2. Create your virtualenv

   ```
    pip3 -p python3.6 virtualenv myenv
   ```
3. Then install djangon in your virtualenv after activating it.

   ```
    pip3 install Django
   ```

You can specify the django version as:

```
  pip3 install Django==1.11
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but for some reason when using

    "sudo apt-get install python3-pip"

I got 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 103 not upgraded.

Comment: Have you tried : 

```sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python3-pip``` first and proceed the steps ?

Comment: I tried sudo remove and then follow the steps. Step 1 reinstalled pip3 with python3.5 so I just ended up going back to where I was. I did try step 2 as well but I received "no such option: -p"

Answer (score 0):

I totally forgot about this post, I just wanna say that pip is a very dangerous tool and should be used with caution since it affects the structure of your computer/server. What I did to solve whatever mess I had created at this time was to:

1. Format the server.
2. To work with and only use pip/pip3 in virtualenv. What makes virtualenvs so awesome is that if something goes wrong then it only goes wrong inside that virtualenv. You will not need to format your computer/server, instead you might have to delete that virtualenv and create a new one.
3. Never use pip/pip3 on your computer/server without a virtualenv, I found out that you don't even need to install it on your root. Best way of using pip is to run a virtualenv and then install it on that virtualenv.

Hope these tips helps preventing people from making huge but easily avoidable mistakes! :D